# rotate ylabel in seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

i have this table:

```
 Wow   Bob  Class  Cook shlook    ban
 1   2.5      0     0      d   44.0
 3   7.5      0     1      f   55.0
 5  12.5      0     0      g   56.0
 4  10.0      0     1      c    3.0
 6  15.0      0     0    esd  323.0
..  ...   ...    ...   ...    ...    ...
 2  14.0      2     1      f    NaN
 2  15.0      2     1      d    2.0
 2  16.0      2     0      d    2.0
 2  17.0      2     0      f    2.0
 2  18.0      2     1      g    NaN
```

and I've been trying to plot a seaborn.pairblot and to dotate the ylables (not ticks) 90 degrees using this code:

```
for axes in g.axes.flat:
     axes.set_ylabel(axes.get_ylabel(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='left')
plt.show()
```

This is the plot i get:
[image]

As you can see, the labels are not rotated.
What should i do?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `g`? Add the code that creates `g` to your question. Also, did you try `rotation=0`?

Comment: g = sns.pairplot(df)

Comment: thank you! it worked, but now the labels are too close to the plots :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the rotation to be 0 and ha to "right":

```
sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,4))

g = sns.pairplot(tips)
for axes in g.axes.flat:
     axes.set_ylabel(axes.get_ylabel(), rotation=0, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

A useful place to check is the matplotlib [vignette](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/text_props.html), :

> You can lay out text with the alignment arguments horizontalalignment,
>   verticalalignment, and multialignment. horizontalalignment controls
>   whether the x positional argument for the text indicates the left,
>   center or right side of the text bounding box.

[image]